# Error passing an Eigen tensor to function

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, eigen3

I am trying to turn the following code to a function:

Update: added full working example to test and run. Thanks.

```
static const int nx = 4; 
static const int ny = 4;
static const int nz = 4;

double Lx = 2*EIGEN_PI;
double Ly = 2*EIGEN_PI;

double A = (2 * EIGEN_PI)/Lx;
double A1 = (2 * EIGEN_PI)/ Ly;
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> eXX(nx,ny,nz); 
eXX.setZero(); 
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> eYY(nx,ny,nz); 
eYY.setZero(); 
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> eZZ(nx,ny,nz); 
eZZ.setZero(); 

double dx = Lx / nx;
double dy = Ly / ny;
double dz = Lz / nz;
for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
                eXX(k,i,j) = i*dx;
                eYY(j,i,k) = j*dy;
                eZZ(j,i,k) = k*dz; 
            }

        }       
    }
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> uFun(nx,ny,nz); 
uFun.setZero(); 
for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
            uFun(k,i,j) = sin(3. * A * eZZ(k,i,j)) * sin(A * eXX(k,i,j)) * cos(A1 * eYY(k,i,j));
             
        }

    }       
}
//Turn this to function
#define IMAG 1
#define REAL 0
fftw_complex *input_array;
fftw_complex *output_array;

input_array = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*nz * sizeof(fftw_complex));
output_array = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*nz * sizeof(fftw_complex));


for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {

      for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {

            for (int k = 0; k < nz; ++k) {
                {
                    input_array[k + nz * (j + ny * i)][REAL] =  uFun(k,i,j);
                    input_array[k + nz * (j + ny * i)][IMAG] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
fftw_plan forward = fftw_plan_dft_3d(nx, ny, nz, input_array, output_array, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(forward);
fftw_destroy_plan(forward);
fftw_cleanup();
```

My attempt:

```
void r2cfft3d(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>& rArr, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> cArr){ 
fftw_complex *input_array;
fftw_complex *output_array;

input_array = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*nz * sizeof(fftw_complex));
output_array = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*nz * sizeof(fftw_complex));


for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {

     for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {

         for (int k = 0; k < nz; ++k) {
                {
                 input_array[k + nz * (j + ny * i)][REAL] =   rArr(k,i,j);
                 input_array[k + nz * (j + ny * i)][IMAG] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
//this is correct 3D fft of uFun = fftn(uFun) in MATLAB
fftw_plan forward = fftw_plan_dft_3d(nx, ny, nz, input_array, output_array, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(forward);
fftw_destroy_plan(forward);
fftw_cleanup(); 

}
```

But I get all these errors:

```
error: variable or field ‘r2cfft3d’ declared void
   27 | void r2cfft3d(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>& rArr, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> cArr);
      |                      ^~~~~~
spectralFunctions3D.h:27:22: error: ‘Tensor’ is not a member of ‘Eigen’
spectralFunctions3D.h:27:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
   27 | void r2cfft3d(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>& rArr, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> cArr);
error: ‘rArr’ was not declared in this scope
   27 | void r2cfft3d(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>& rArr, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> cArr);
error: ‘cArr’ was not declared in this scope
   27 | void r2cfft3d(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>& rArr, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> cArr);
      |                                                                                      ^~~~
```

I don't understand these errors, espically that the code works fine before trying to turn it into a function. I am more familiar with passing Eigen matrices to function but not Eigen tensors. Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mre]? Especially what includes are you using at what place?

Comment: @chtz Sure! I will add the code I am using here as a small example

Comment: your code snippet does not show the includes?

Comment: If the code you show after "My attempt" is really everything inside that file, your problem is that you need to include every header which you are using (the Eigen-Tensor header as well as the fftw header in your case). If these are actually included, please carefully read again how to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compile this fine by including all the relevant headers (especially `#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>`).
Since you are using `const` sizes for the Eigen Tensors you could define them as fixed size with

```
Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<nx, ny, nz>>
```

Also take a look at this: https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Column_002dmajor-Format.html , maybe you can avoid the conversion from column-major to row-major and pass directly the pointer to the Eigen Tensor.